# $('body').on('click') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to trigger an action after a click anywhere on the body, the code is:

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="paper"></div> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}
.paper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    background-color: white;}
```

and js:

```
window.onload = function(){
           $('body').on('click',function(){
               console.log("click");
           })
       }
```

My problem is that the click is only registered when I click in our next to the div; if I click below nothing happens.

I am a bit confused by this, isn't the body the entire page? If I change the background-color of the body the entire background in the browser gets that colour, but using it with jQuery is different?

(jQuery is properly loaded and there are no error logs)

Comment: The body doesn't always cover the entire viewport, you seem to have it mixed up with the `document`

Comment: But anyway it seems to be inconsistent with the fact that the background changes the color in the whole viewport.

Comment: add css `html, body {min-height:100%}`  and try the click again. Will see what adeneo is talking about

Comment: And if you want the "entire screen" to be clickable, always use `$(document)`

Comment: @Ultimate_noob
The body is not the whole page, well visually it appears so, but there are things like event propagation, bubbling, event capture going beyond on what is rendered visible on screen.
Check my reply below, that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('html').on('click', function(){
   console.log('click');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to achieve the desired effect, is to put your click handler on your document, like this :

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    console.log("click");
});
```

Now, also want to make sure your JavaScript code is at the very bottom of your HTML file, like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
      // header content goes here
    </head>
    <body>
      // body content goes here
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('click',function(){
                console.log("click");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you can not or do not want to put your JS code at the very bottom of your HTML, you could also wrap your click handle with `$(document).ready()`, like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click',function(){
        console.log("click");
    });
});
```

See [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q4h8us8b/1/) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting on `'body'` may not be what you expect (you may want document instead), but here is the correct syntax:

```
$('body').on('click', 'selector', function(){
    /* do something here */
})
```

Comment: That's the same example they write

Answer (score 0):

Target document

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(document).on('click',function(){
           console.log("click");
alert("clicked");
       });
});
```

You have to have the on load wrapper, or you get an initial undefined for $. Can obviously be doc ready, but you have load in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try this.this will help to you

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- js--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').click(function(){
        alert(" ");
    });

 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*I suggest you to check your jquery is working.simply put an `alert(" ")` and check it before you go for huge one.hope this helps to you.cheers!!!